# Music effects in Win RT

Tags: audio, windows-runtime

What is another way to play sounds in Win RT instead of using Media Element? I'd like to play some "play-and-forget" sounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have multiple MediaElements or you can use XAudio2 or WASAPI, but multiple MediaElements is possibly the easiest way. Just track which one is done playing so you can reuse it.